# How to use gpg, gpg-agent, especially for .authinfo.gpg?

Tags: gnupg, gnus

(kubuntu, but trying to remain platform independent in my approaches.)

Either of conceptual explanations or necessary steps are appreciated.

I'm reading through the documentation, and tried to get `gpg-agent` to work once, but am getting discouraged as each attempt will require a reboot, and I don't really understand how it works in the first place (just cutting and pasting code).

I want to use `gpg-agent` so that I can try out `GNUS` without entering passphrase on `.authinfo.gpg` every time I open `GNUS`.

---

I'd like to understand more about the process before I dig into the problem more.

1. Is a `gpg --gen-key` necessary before using `gpg-agent` for `.authinfo.gpg`?
2. Are the config lines mentioning `SSH` necessary for my minimal use of `gpg`?
3. Is `.authinfo.gpg` to take position on some keychain? Does that keychain itself need a master key?

Please correct me on the imagined flow of the process. (Is an absent key needed?). I regret that it is very sparse.

1. After boot, initialization turns on the `gpg` daemon, and other related settings are made.
2. When `GNUS` accesses `.authinfo.gpg`, it caches something with `gpg-agent`.

---

Here are some more details I consider.

The following variables are set

```
GPG_AGENT_INFO    ${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info
GPG_TTY           $(TTY)
```

In `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, we need to see `use-agent`. I leave the dummy `#default-key ********` commented out, as I believe it's only needed if you have more than one key.

In `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, we need to see

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-qt4
no-grab
default-cache-ttl 1800
```

(Though, `pinentry-qt4` might be replaced with other present versions, such as `pinentry-curses`.)

---

There may be some redundancies, but I've also seen lines for I assume `.bashrc`, such as `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`, or

```
gpg-agent --daemon \
    --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
```

(I've omitted lines regarding `SSH`, as I assume I don't need this for now.)

---

I've seen a troubleshooting command

```
echo "test" | gpg -ase -r 0xMYKEYID | gpg
```

but since I wasn't sure if I needed a key in the first place, I didn't go further with this.

Comment: You're using a debian-based system. `gpg` is GnuPG version 1, which does not support using `gpg-agent`. Use `gpg2` instead.

Comment: @JensErat, thank you, will step back through instructions starting at [GnuPG and EasyPG Assistant Configuration - Emacs auth-source Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/auth/GnuPG-and-EasyPG-Assistant-Configuration.html), keeping this in mind.

Comment: @JensErat, brilliant! I played around a bit more, and eventually googled "emacs gpg2", and tried `(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/bin/gpg2")`. It seems to work, thank you!

Comment: gpg and gpg-agent work fine here with a Debian setup. Specifically gpg and not gpg2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my very amateur tutorial in reply to my own question.

To check if `gpg-agent` is already enabled, try

```
ps aux | grep gpg
```

I find

```
iam@heeere:/e$ ps aux | grep gpg
iam       1490  0.0  0.0  16728   900 ?        Ss   17:25   0:00 gpg-agent --daemon --sh
iam       2611  0.0  0.0  11748   912 pts/0    S+   17:33   0:00 grep --color=auto gpg
```

This together with

```
(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/bin/gpg2")
```

seemed to solve my problem. As Jens Erat pointed out, `gpg-agent` is associated with `gpg2`, not `gpg`.

In fact, I deleted all the modifications I had made from

> [GnuPG and EasyPG Assistant Configuration - Emacs auth-source Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/auth/GnuPG-and-EasyPG-Assistant-Configuration.html),

and it still worked perfectly. That is, no `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`, no `gpg-agent.conf` needed. Though, I may add some back, for instance `default-cache-ttl`. And while `pinentry-curses` looks appealing, I think greater minds than mine have struggled with preventing `gpg-agent` using pop-up from Emacs, so I'll leave that alone.